# How to make each Multilist Item editable in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

Some items in a `MultiListField` have to be displayed in html, but in 2 columns, as:

> Item1 Item2
>   Item3 Item4

```
<div id="menu-section" runat="server">
 <div class="clearfix">      
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>Item1 Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>Item2 Name</p>
    </div>      
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">      
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>Item3 Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>Item4 Name</p>
    </div>      
 </div>
</div>
```

The content author should be able to edit each item from Experience editor.
If it was a single column, I would accomplish this using `asp:Repeater` and `sc:` controls.

So, instead, I string built the html and rendered on page.

**C#**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<div class=\"clearfix\">");
.
.
..
menu-section.innerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

Though, the items are rendered as desired, I have no clue how to make them editable.

Enveloping `menu-section` inside a `sc:EditFrame` will allow only add/remove/sorting of the items but not editing each item.

Any thoughts, how to do this?

Comment: Why not just have a row of `col-xs-6` within a single `<div class="clearfix">`? It's a straight forward repeater then and the items will just render inline with one another automatically start a new row as required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the FieldRenderer to render the field:

```
sb.Append(FieldRenderer.Render(item1, "Name");
```

When on the Page/Experience Editor, this will render the item as editable.

Comment: Although this will work perfectly, you should do yourself the pleasure to convert your UserControl to a WebControl. Creating html as strings and outputting that in usercontrols is not really a good practice...

Comment: Totally agree, yet the question was how to make the fields editable.

Comment: True - just a small attempt to get people to write decent code ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would go back to your repeater solution, and try with nested repeaters.

First, get your datasource into a list of item lists (you can use a collection of collections for example). In your case each internal list will have 2 items (for 2 columns).

Bind this datasource to your outer repeater which could generate the `<div class="clearfix">.. </div>` for each entry (list) it can find. Within this repeater create another inner repeater and bind the entry (inner list - in your case a collection of 2 items) to it. Your inner repeater can generate the `<div class="col-xs-6">` elements and use a sc: control.

This will make them editable, but you will still need the editframe to add/remove/sort...